# How to retrieve the name of the author ( the user) associated with each commits in svn log?

Tags: svn

Is there a short way to read the name of the user who made a particular commit to svn server?  I.e. given a revision number, is there a short way of retrieving the name of the user (username) who made that particular change?

Answer (score 1):

Use `svn propget --revprop`:

```
svn propget svn:author URL --revprop -r REVISION
```

For example:

```
svn propget http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf --revprop svn:author -r 1482368
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`svn log`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html)? You can parse the output to get the username.

- E.g. `svn log https://server/svn/repository/ -r 123` will give you the following output:

  ```
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  r123 | username | 2003-01-17 22:56:19 -0600 (Fri, 17 Jan 2003) | 1 line

  Changed something
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ```
- You can also add `--xml` argument to get nice XML output which is easier to parse.

  `svn log https://server/svn/repository/ -r 123 --xml`:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <log>
      <logentry revision="1">
          <author>username</author>
          <date>2003-01-17T22:56:19.483622Z</date>
          <msg>Changed something</msg>
      </logentry>
  </log>
  ```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I know I can use the --XML to have the result in XML and parse through the result. I was wondering if there is a short way to directly retrieve the username given a revision number.

Comment: @bAmy: Check my reply how to use svn propget --revprop to get revision author only.